# Error Logging Into Magento 2: Open Source admin panel

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento2, admin, sodium

SO I followed instructions here:
https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento2-4-2-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/

to install Magento 2 into a fresh install of xammppv3.3.0 running Php7. Once its time to get into the Admin account, It first said the information was incorrect or locked. I ran the commands

```
(php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>)
and
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'NewP@ssword'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'adminusername';
```

- all commands came back successful. The I recieve the following:
  [Error processing your request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jkKn.png)

So i look into the log and see the following message:

> main.CRITICAL: This is not implemented, as it is not possible to
> implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP
> {"report_id":"33485650bd9de85e8178e26a25bd0f1347c7c9d625b14c2b7167b732b909c9b0","exception":"[object]
> (SodiumException(code: 0): This is not implemented, as it is not
> possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP
> at
> D:\xammp\htdocs\magento\vendor\paragonie\sodium_compat\src\Compat.php:1939)"}
> []

According to all searches ive done, this is due to sodium not being used in my PHP, but it is:

[image: php -m]

the ';' in front of sodium in my php.ini is removed, but I still cant get into magento admin. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP version 7.4 please switch to PHP version 7.3. For version 7.3 the stability will be higher with the versions of Magento (it is true for the current latest Magento versions)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running php 7.4?

Also, you've removed the ";" from sodium in your php.ini, but have you got the extension installed in XAMPP?

Edit: apologies I've just spotted you have checked the extension is installed. Are you running PHP 7.4 or later?